# Getting value from ajax calling using xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I am making a request using post method. I am not able to find the value of response text. May be i lack the knowledge on how to get the response text. If a data exist in a database i am trying to tell the user that he is able to post the data otherwise he will get an alert that he need to change the name.
Here is my ajax call:-
function  checkAddedNew(univ_name,term_no,dept_name,uid,year)
            {

```
    var getName=document.getElementById("add_new_name").value;      
    var getTitle=document.getElementById("add_new_title").value;    

    var hasSpace=getTitle.indexOf(' ');


    if(hasSpace >= 0)
    {
        alert("Please fill up the title without space");
    }
    else
    {
        if(getName&& getTitle)
        {               
            var r=confirm("Do you want to add?");
        }
        else if(!getName && getTitle)
        {
            alert("Please fill up the name");
        }
        else if(getName && !getTitle)
        {
            alert("Please fill up the title");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Please fill up the form.");
        }


    if (r==true )
        {
            var xmlhttp;    


            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

                alert(http.responseText);
                location.reload();
                }
              }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","../addnew/check",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                   
            xmlhttp.send("title="+getTitle+"&name="+getCourseName+"&name="+univ_name+"&term_no="+term_no+"&department_name="+dept_name+"&uid="+uid+"&year="+year);
        }

    }

}
```

and i am here getting the response xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 .And here is my controller :-

```
function check()
    {


        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');   
        $university_name=$this->input->post('university_name');
        $term_no=$this->input->post('term_no');
        $department_name=$this->input->post('department_name');
        $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
        $year=$this->input->post('year');   



        $CI =& get_instance();                  
        $log_username=$CI->session->userdata('username');   

        $now = time();
        $human = unix_to_human($now);

        $this->load->model('model');
        $isUnique=$this->model->checkNew($name,$title,$log_username,$human,$term_no,$university_name,$year,$department_name,$uid);      


        if($isUnique)
        {

            $this->course_model->insertNewCourse($course_name,$course_title,$log_username,$human,$term_no,$university_name,$year,$department_name,$uid);


        }




    }
```

Comment: you should check out jquery

Comment: don't understand @geedubb

Comment: jquery is a javascript library, which amongst other things contains functions which abstarct away XmlHttpRequest. It might be worth a look http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

The variable `http` is not defined, it should be `xmlhttp`

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    //or
    //alert(this.responseText);
    location.reload();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `alert(http.responseText);` but you never define `http`. Your object is called `xmlhttp`.